# How to prove the remainder of the binomial series is zero when $0\leq x<1$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients

Suppose $0\leq x<1$, the Taylor expansion of the $(1+x)^\lambda$ at $x_0=0$ should be convergent. I want to prove this by using when $n\to \infty$ the remainder of this expansion is approaching zero without using other convergence test

$$ (1+x)^\lambda=1+\lambda x+\dfrac{\lambda(\lambda-1)}{2!}x^2+\cdots + \dfrac{\lambda (\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-(n-1))}{n!}x^n +r_n(x)$$

The remainder can be expressed as the Lagrange form $$ r_n(x)=\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$
where $\xi \in (0,x)$
and $$ f^{(n+1)}(\xi) = \lambda (\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-(n-1))(\lambda-n)(1+\xi)^{\lambda-(n+1)} $$
Thus the remainder is $$ \dfrac{\lambda (\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-(n-1))(\lambda-n)(1+\xi)^{\lambda-(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$

Then I simplify it as
$$ \dfrac{\lambda (\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-(n-1))(\lambda-n)}{(n+1)!}(1+\xi)^{\lambda}(
\frac{x}{1+\xi})^{n+1}$$.

And $n\to \infty$ it's clear to see that since $1+\xi>x$, $\ \ (\dfrac{x}{1+\xi})^{n+1}$ this term will go zero. Also $(1+\xi)^\lambda$ isn't a zero or infinity term

However, I don't know how to deal with $ \dfrac{\lambda (\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-(n-1))(\lambda-n)}{(n+1)!}=\displaystyle \binom{\lambda}{n+1}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Thus, any help on this? Or maybe there exists some other ways to deal with the remainder?

Comment: Ratio test, maybe>

Comment: In fact, I know how to prove the convergence by using the ratio test, but the point is to prove the convergence by only using the remainder...

Comment: Well, $n$ will eventually exceed $\lambda$ quite significantly, and the numerator of the binomial coefficient will be completely dominated by the denominator $(n+1)!$. So long as $\xi^n$ remains bounded (i.e. less $\xi\lt 1$) we are happy (after some details, of course)

Comment: Yeah, intuitively this is right. Is there a way show that what $ \lambda(\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-n)$ will be when $n\to \infty$? Or are there some ways to rigorously say that $(n+1)!$ is definitely will be dominant? I know I can change $(n+1)!$ by using the Stirling approximation, but the numerator...

Comment: $n\gg\lambda$ simply, for large $n$. So $(n+1)n(n-1)\gg\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [alternating series theorem with its "estimation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Alternating_series_estimation_theorem) saying that if the general term of the series, here:

$$a_n=\dfrac{\lambda (\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-(n-1))}{n!}x^n\tag{1}$$

- (i) tends to $0$ in a decreasing way in absolute value.
- (ii) with alternate signs ($sign(a_{n+1})=-sign(a_{n}$),

then the series is convergent with

$$|S_n-S| \le |a_{n+1}|$$

In words: the error, i.e., the absolute value of the difference between the partial sum $S_n:=a_1+a_2+\cdots a_n$ and the total sum $S$ is bounded by the first "neglected term".

Here, in order to have the two conditions (i) and (ii) fulfilled, we need to drop a certain finite number of terms (as we are going to explain) **which is not harmful**.

Let us use the following consequence of (1):

$$a_{n} \ = \ a_n \ x \ \underbrace{\frac{(\lambda-(n-1))}{n}}_{K_n}$$

- condition (ii) is fulfilled for all $n > n_0:=\lfloor\lambda +1\rfloor $ (integer part of $\lambda$ ; I assume $\lambda >-1$) because for $n>n_0$,  $K_n=\frac{(\lambda+1)-n}{n}$ is negative. Moreover $|K_n|<1$ ; therefore

$$|a_n|<|a_{n-1}|x$$

As $x<1$, the latter relationship proves that $|a_n| \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

- condition (i) is fullfilled when

$$\lambda -(n-1) \le n \ \iff \ 2n-1 \ge  \lambda$$

Otherwise said when:

$$ \ n \ge n_1:=\lfloor\frac{\lambda+1}{2}+1)\rfloor  $$

Therefore, if $n \ge \max(n_0,n_1)$, the upsaid theorem can be applied.